# Got Error(11,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is the Snippet of my Procedure.
**Context_value is Clob
** Order_id is int

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY UPDATE_RECORD AS 

Procedure updateRecord(orderId  IN ORDER_CONTEXT.ORDER_ID%TYPE
) IS 


  BEGIN



    update ORDER_CONTEXT 
  set context_value= (
   select to_clob(replace( (context_value).getClobVal(),'xyz','abc'))
  from ORDER_CONTEXT where CONTEXT_NAME='IEOD' and  ORDER_ID=orderId
  )
  where CONTEXT_NAME='IEOD' and  ORDER_ID=orderId ;

   COMMIT;
  END updateRecord;

END UPDATE_RECORD;
```

Error is 
Error(11,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(11,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB

Comment: what data type is context_value in order_Context? and order_ID in order_Context?  and what value is being passed into updateRecord.orderID

Comment: context_value is clob, order_id is int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cast your context_value as datatype XMLtype using XMLTYPE() as shown.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY UPDATE_RECORD
AS
PROCEDURE updateRecord(
    orderId IN ORDER_CONTEXT.ORDER_ID%TYPE )
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE ORDER_CONTEXT
  SET context_value=
    (SELECT to_clob(REPLACE( (XMLTYPE('<root>'
      ||context_value
      ||'</root>')).getClobVal(),'xyz','abc'))
    FROM ORDER_CONTEXT
    WHERE CONTEXT_NAME='IEOD'
    AND ORDER_ID      =orderId
    )
  WHERE CONTEXT_NAME='IEOD'
  AND ORDER_ID      =orderId ;
  COMMIT;
END updateRecord;
END UPDATE_RECORD;
/
```